# PHP to receive data being sent to a port

Tags: php, sockets

I have a device that is sending data to a port on my local computer (for now, it will go to a site later) the following code receives the data from the port using PHP.  I have to enter 127.0.0.1/web/1.php (my filename) into the url for this to work.  This will be a problem when I eventually go live, also the socket closes each time I receive my data.  How can I keep listening and how can the php file run without me entering it in the URL.

Any advice is gratefully received, I have a VB background and PHP and web is very new to me! Thanks

This is my current PHP

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);

/* Allow the script to hang around waiting for connections. */ set_time_limit(0);

/* Turn on implicit output flushing so we see what we're getting  * as it comes in. */ ob_implicit_flush();

$address = '192.168.1.70'; $port = 10000;

if (($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP)) === false) {
    echo "socket_create() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "\n"; }

if (socket_bind($sock, $address, $port) === false) {
    echo "socket_bind() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n"; }

if (socket_listen($sock, 5) === false) {
    echo "socket_listen() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n"; }

do {
    if (($msgsock = socket_accept($sock)) === false) {
        echo "socket_accept() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
        break;
    }

    do {
        if (false === ($buf = socket_read($msgsock, 2048, PHP_NORMAL_READ))) {
            echo "socket_read() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($msgsock)) . "\n";
            break 2;
        }
        if (!$buf = trim($buf)) {
            continue;   
        }
        if ($buf == 'quit') {
            break;
        }
        if ($buf == 'shutdown') {
            socket_close($msgsock);
            break 2;
        }
        $talkback = "PHP: You said '$buf'.\n";      $file=fopen("welcome.txt","a+") or exit("Unable to open file!");        fwrite($file, $talkback);       fclose($file);
        socket_write($msgsock, $talkback, strlen($talkback));
        echo "$buf\n";
    } while (true);
    socket_close($msgsock); } while (true);

socket_close($sock);
```

Comment: PHP is not going to be the best language for a generic socket like this. At least in the past when I have used it, I have run into numerous memory issues.

Comment: Hi, thanks, can I ask what you would recommend?

Answer (score 0):

You can deamonise the script and run it from the command line - as per Colins comment above - PHP may not be the best language for this - but when I have done it perviously I have also added a monitor to observe and relaunch the script if for any reason it stops running.

If you are running on Unix then making the script executable e.g.

```
chmod a+x <script name>
```

And adding

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
```

To the start of the script will allow you to execute it from the command line.

Then use a package like Deamon Tools

http://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html

To launch and monitor that your script is running.

Comment: I will look into that thanks, using Windows but a great starting point.  I am interested in other ways of doing this as not yet tied to PHP